# How do I set configuration for a group in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my Phaser 3 game I have a group called OBS that stores all the obstacles sprites.

```
OBS = this.physics.add.group
```

I want to set the velocity of every child created from this group to a particular value say

```
setVelocityY=40
```

So every object that is in group OBS will move at velocity 40. How do I set a configuration for the group such that every object that I add to it moves at the given velocity and shares other common properties?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that.

1. using config - 
   You can pass [PhysicsGroupConfig](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/global.html#PhysicsGroupConfig) while creating [group](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html#Group__anchor), and set `velocityY` in that config that will set `velocityY` of every children of that group. You can set many properties in config. Check out the docs.
2. using group's methods like `setVelocity` or `setVelocityY` - if you want to set velocity after creating group you can use group's methods like [setvelocityY](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html#setVelocityY__anchor) or [setVelocity](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group.html#setVelocity__anchor).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop to add properties to all the child elements.
Eg. if you have 3 child elements, you can do it like this:

```
var OBSPositions = [
    { x: 50, y: 80 },
    { x: 50, y: 480 },
    { x: 300, y: 480 }
];

OBS = this.physics.add.group;
for (var i = 0; i < OBSPositions.length; i++) {
    var OBSchild = OBS.create(
        OBSPositions[i].x,
        OBSPositions[i].y,
        'OBSsprite'
    ).setScale(0.13, 0.13);

    OBSchild.setVelocityY = 40;
}
```